# drracket function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but received 14

Tags: racket

hey I am really frustrated with my code. Ive been trying to implement a code that filters through a list of structs and filters out any struct that has not the same id as another struct.

I unfortunately don't know what to do anymore. The only error message I always get is:

*function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but received 14*

Here is my code:

```
(define (make-filter lst trlst)
     
  (filter (lambda(x) (equal? (route-section-id lst) (traffic-jam-section-id x))) trlst))
                          
(define it
  (list
   (make-traffic-jam 14 7)
   (make-traffic-jam 14 7 )
   (make-traffic-jam 14 7)))
(define some-items
  (list
   (make-route-section (14 "highway" 18 19))))

(check-expect (make-filter (some-items) (it))0)
```

Comment: The expression `(14 "highway" 18 19)` has 14 in the function position. That means it is trying to call `14` as the name of a functions. If there are supposed to be 4 arguments to `make-route-section`, remove the parentheses. If the argument to `make-route-section` should be a list, you probably want `(list 14 "highway" 18 19)`.

Comment: I am so thankful right now. I like looked at that code for hours and did not yet see that. really thank you :). I now feel very stupid xD.

Comment: Happens all the time to me too.

Comment: @clartaq You should write an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheme (and most Lisps) assume that a symbol immediately following a left parenthesis refers to a function to be executed. The error message tells you that the interpreter found a number in that position rather than the name of a function.

In your code, the procedure `some-items` has an expression `(14 "highway" 18 19)` with a number where a function name is expected. That is the source of the error.

If the function `make-route-section` expects four individual arguments, just remove the parentheses around the offending expression. If `make-route-section` is expecting a list of arguments, use `(list 14 "highway" 18 19)`. In this case, `list` is the name of a function that builds and returns a list.